# What is the best proportion sand/cement to do pavers?

Tags: concrete, patio, cement

I want to make my own patio using pre-made molds.  I would like to know if I can use only cement and sand.  Will it be resistant or do I need to add aggregates.  What should be the ratio?

Comment: If you look at any commercially made pavers, they are either brick or concrete.  Concrete is cement + aggregates.  Why do they use aggregates?  It's because that greatly increases the strength of the finished produce.  If you just use cement + sand you will essentially have mortar which is much weaker than concrete.  Of course you can leave out the aggregate but you may not have a good finished product.

Comment: In other words, you've asked an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). Better to ask what mix to use in general. Feel free to revise.

Comment: I agree with jwh20. Turkey grit sand mix would be what I would use Turkey grit is smaller than pea gravel but larger than sand it works well. In my area it is fairly inexpensive as it is hard to separate but works well for what you are doing.